# How to mix spa/traditional-multipage hybrid app with vue.js/node, express, mysql?

Tags: vue.js, express, single-page-application, hybrid

I would like to know how to make a hybrid web e-commerce with Vue, Node, Express. SEO reasons..
I like traditional-true-multipage app approach, but with Vue, there's much less hassle with interactivity, I also like the speed and seamlessness.

I see some apps online that are using Vue.js but have a page reload on basic navigation routes (WizzAir, Behance). When a page loads it behaves like standard SPA.

How is this achieved? Are there multiple spa-s for each page(doesn't make sense at all), or is Vue.js used without a build and SFC-s?

p.s Are there any true SPA e-commerce websites out there?

Comment: Look into server side rendering (SSR) and Nuxt.